# query to filter out results containing html tags

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query captions that don't have the `<strong>` tag in them via the following query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `instagram_shop_picture` 
WHERE  `caption` NOT LIKE  '%<strong>%'
```

Why does it still give me results that have `<strong>` in them?

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 possible problems here.

1) Trim down the whitesapce before %%

2) Take the case sensitiveness into account

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `instagram_shop_picture` 
WHERE  upper(`caption`) NOT LIKE  '%<STRONG>%'
```